# DATEDIFF date with EXISTS/IN another date table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there must be some question like me. Seems I cannot find the question, I sorry to ask this question.

Below is table #DayShift

```
ID   |Name   |Date        |DateType
1     Hafiz   2020-05-03   WORKDAY
2     Hafiz   2020-05-04   WORKDAY       
3     Hafiz   2020-05-15   WORKDAY
```

Below is a table #LeaveTransaction

```
ID   |Name   |LeaveType    |DateApplyStart   |DateApplyEnd
1     Hafiz   Annual Leave   2020-05-01        2020-05-05
```

Using SQL Query below:

```
select id,Name, LeaveType, DateApplyStart, DateApplyEnd
    , DATEDIFF (DAY, DateApplyStart, DateApplyEnd)+1 as TotalApply
from LeaveTransaction
```

I get a result like below:

```
ID   |Name   |LeaveType    |DateApplyStart   |DateApplyEnd  |TotalApply
1     Hafiz   Annual Leave   2020-05-01        2020-05-05        5
```

What I want to get like below:

```
ID   |Name   |LeaveType    |DateApplyStart   |DateApplyEnd  |TotalApply
1     Hafiz   Annual Leave   2020-05-01        2020-05-05        2
```

Appreciate I get help on this. Thanks.

Comment: what is the logic for TotalApply? I mean how are you calculating `2`?

Comment: DATEDIFF (DAY, DateApplyStart, DateApplyEnd)-2 should do it

Comment: sorry for my late reply, actually i want calculate "TotalApply" from table LeaveTransaction that calculate the range "DateApplyStart, DateApplyEnd" that have existed date in table DayShift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/310331/9).

```
select 
  lt.id,
  ds.Name, 
  LeaveType, 
  DateApplyStart, 
  DateApplyEnd,
  count(date) as TotalApply
from LeaveTransaction lt
join DaysShift ds
on lt.name = ds.name
where date between DateApplyStart and DateApplyEnd
group by
  lt.id,
  ds.Name, 
  LeaveType, 
  DateApplyStart, 
  DateApplyEnd
```

output:

```
*--------------------------------------------------------------*
| id  Name  LeaveType  DateApplyStart  DateApplyEnd  TotalApply|
*--------------------------------------------------------------*
| 1  Hafiz Annual Leave  2020-05-01      2020-05-05      2     |
*--------------------------------------------------------------*
```